# It's getting harder and harder to be composite these days

Tags: code-golf, sequence, primes

Given a non-empty list **L** of integers greater than **1**, we define **d(L)** as the smallest positive integer such that **n + d(L)** is [composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_number) for each **n** in **L**.

We define the sequence **a<sub>n</sub>** as:

- **a<sub>0</sub> = 2**
- **a<sub>i+1</sub>** is the smallest integer greater than **a<sub>i</sub>** such that **d(a<sub>0</sub>, ..., a<sub>i</sub>, a<sub>i+1</sub>) >  d(a<sub>0</sub>, ..., a<sub>i</sub>)**

### Your task

You may either:

- Take an integer **N** and return the **N-th** term of the sequence (0-indexed or 1-indexed)
- Take an integer **N** and return the first **N** terms of the sequence
- Take no input and print the sequence forever

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

It's OK if your code is getting slow as **N** gets larger, but it should at least find the 20 first terms in less than 2 minutes.

### First terms

- **a<sub>0</sub> = 2** and **d(2) = 2** (we need to add 2 so that 2+2 is composite)
- **a<sub>1</sub> = 3** because **d(2, 3) = 6** (we need to add 6 so that 2+6 and 3+6 are composite)
- **a<sub>2</sub> = 5** because **d(2, 3, 5) = 7** (we need to add 7 so that 2+7, 3+7 and 5+7 are all composite), whereas **d(2, 3, 4)** is still equal to **6**
- etc.

Below are the 100 first terms of the sequence (unknown on OEIS at the time of posting).

```
  2,   3,   5,   6,  10,  15,  17,  19,  22,  24,
 30,  34,  35,  39,  41,  47,  51,  54,  56,  57,
 70,  79,  80,  82,  92,  98, 100, 103, 106, 111,
113, 116, 135, 151, 158, 162, 165, 179, 183, 186,
191, 192, 200, 210, 217, 223, 226, 228, 235, 240,
243, 260, 266, 274, 277, 284, 285, 289, 298, 307,
309, 317, 318, 329, 341, 349, 356, 361, 374, 377,
378, 382, 386, 394, 397, 405, 409, 414, 417, 425,
443, 454, 473, 492, 494, 502, 512, 514, 519, 527,
528, 560, 572, 577, 579, 598, 605, 621, 632, 642
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 24 bytes

```
Pu+GfP_+Tf!fP_+ZYG)eGQ]2
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Pu%2BGfP_%2BTf%21fP_%2BZYG%29eGQ%5D2&input=10&debug=0)

Basically, we start with `[2]`, then add elements 1 at a time by alternately finding `d`, then adding an element, and so forth. Outputs the first `n` elements of the sequence.

Contains a filter inside a first integer filter inside a first integer filter inside an apply repeatedly loop.

**Explanation:**

```
Pu+GfP_+Tf!fP_+ZYG)eGQ]2
 u                   Q]2    Starting with `[2]`, do the following as many times
                            as the input
         f        )         Starting from 1 and counting upward, find d where
          !f     G          None of the elements in the current list
            P_+ZY           plus d give a prime.
    f              eG       Starting from the end of the current list and counting
                            upward, find the first number which
     P_+T                   plus d gives a prime.
  +G                        Append the new number to the current list
P                           Trim the last element of the list
```

There's obvious repeated effort between the two "Add and check if prime" calls, but I'm not sure how to eliminate it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 31 bytes

```
ṛ,;1+ÆPẸṆʋ1#ⱮẎ</
Ḷß€‘Ṫç1#ƊḢƲ2⁸?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUYAuf9qZWxsef//4bmbLDsxK8OGUOG6uOG5hsqLMSPisa7huo48LwrhuLbDn@KCrOKAmOG5qsOnMSPGiuG4osayMuKBuD////85)

Jelly sucks at recurrence sequences. :/

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 74 bytes

```
K`__;
"$+"{/;(?!(__+)\1+\b)/+`;
;_
.+$
$&¶$&
)/;(__+)\1+$/+`.+$
_$&_
%`\G_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3zshPt6aS0lFW6la31rDXlEjPl5bM8ZQOyZJU187wZrLOp5LT1uFS0Xt0DYVNS5NoBqoAhWgNEgmXkUtnks1IcY9/v9/Q0sA) 0-indexed. Explanation:

```
K`__;
```

Each line `i` in the workarea contains two unary values, `aᵢ;d+aᵢ`. We start with `a₀=2` and `d+a₀=0` (because it's golfier).

```
"$+"{
...
)
```

Repeat the loop `N` times.

```
/;(?!(__+)\1+\b)/+`
```

Repeat while there is at least one non-composite number.

```
;
;_
```

Increment `d`.

```
.+$
$&¶$&
```

Duplicate the last line, copying `aᵢ₋₁` to `aᵢ`.

```
/;(__+)\1+$/+`
```

Repeat while `d+aᵢ` is composite.

```
.+$
_$&_
```

Increment `aᵢ`.

```
%`\G_
```

Convert the results to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), <s>138</s> <s>130</s> 128 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$l=until(\v=all(\n=any((<)1o gcd(n+v))[2..n+v-1])l)inc 1
```

```
map hd(iterate(\l=hd[[n:l]\\n<-[hd l..]| $[n:l]> $l])[2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcyxCsMgFIXhvU/hkEEpEdKxxE7tUOiWMTpc1CbC9SYkJhDos9dKp/Nzhs@iB8pxcht6FiFQDnGelsS65B60nypUG6WAXO8KsAwpoIPzVjQTG6zjdN6F6C9SlqgbI1AEsqzJXYKiqGLObHQ8JL9A8lyjGl3f0xWN1tTW/egYSmk@rPqfN1ahKZ4R@WvfCMOa6@cr3w@CGOz6Aw)

***Expanded:***

```
$l=until(\v=all(\n=any((<)1o gcd(n+v))[2..n+v-1])l)inc 1
$l=until(                                         )inc 1  // first value from 1 upwards where _
         \v=all(                                )l        // _ is true for everything in l
                \n=any(              )[2..n+v-1]          // any of [2,3..n+v-1] match _
                             gcd(n+v)                     // the gcd of (n+v) and ^
                           o                              // (composed) ^ is _
                       (<)1                               // greater than 1
```

```
map hd(iterate(\l=hd[[n:l]\\n<-[hd l..]| $[n:l]> $l])[2]) 
map hd(                                                 ) // the first element of each list in _
       iterate(                                     )[2]  // infinite repeated application of _ to [2]
               \l=hd[                              ]      // the head of _
                     [n:l]                                // n prepended to l
                          \\n<-[hd l..]                   // for every integer n greater than the head of l
                                       | $[n:l]> $l       // where d(n0..ni+1) > d(n0..ni)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), <s>145</s> 130 bytes

```julia
~L=(x=1;while any(map(m->all(m%i>0 for i=2:m-1),L+x));x+=1;end;x)
!n=n<1?[2]:(P=!(n-1);t=P[end]+1;while ~[P;t]<=~P;t+=1;end;[P;t])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYyxCoMwFEX3fkUcCi@kgsnQwfjsDzhkDw6BWpqSPEUsTRd/PQ0Fpwv3nnNf7@DdNed9QEgo9efpw8QcfSG6BWLduxAgnn3fsMe8Mo@qjbXkl0EkznUSRZnorhM/VYTUyZtVYwsGK6CC6Q2NLfsojufdGr2NHe4lDvlf8bysnrZAUKmG5x8)

*(-15 bytes using my new and improved golfing skills - operator overloads, replacing conditional by ternary and hence removing `return` keyword.)*

**Expanded**:

```julia
function primecheck(m)
    all(m%i>0 for i∈2:m-1)
end

function d(L)
    x = 1
    while any(map(primecheck, L+x))
        x += 1
    end
    return x
end

function a(n)
    n > 0 || return [2]
    Prev = a(n-1)
    term = Prev[end] + 1
    while d([Prev;term]) ≤ d(Prev)
        term += 1
    end
    return [Prev;term]
end
```